# How to make #states work when dependant element is modified with JS .click()

Tags: 7, javascript

We have custom JS that changes the value of some radio buttons using .click() and we have #states defined in other form elements that react to changes in those radio buttons.

The #states work fine when the radios are manually clicked but don't work when they are clicked through our custom JS .click() (the radio button values change, but the #states are not fired).

This is how the #states is defined:

```
'#states' => array(
  'invisible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_measure_system[und]"]' => array('value' => 'METRIC'),
   ),
),
```

and this is how the JS modifies the radio button:

```
$('a.tab-metric').click(function() {
$('#edit-field-measure-system-und-metric').click();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `$('#edit-field-measure-system-und-metric').click();` try `$('#edit-field-measure-system-und-metric').attr('checked', true).trigger('click');` or simply ``$('#edit-field-measure-system-und-metric').trigger('click');``

Comment: Quick note: Post jQuery 1.6.1 `.prop()`(and not `.attr()`) method is preferred way to get/set boolean style attributes like 'checked' and 'disabled'. So the above will become- `$('#edit-field-measure-system-und-metric').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');`

I guess I need to change my habit as well :)

Comment: hey @mirnazim! thanks so much for your reply. I'm afraid it doesn't work though :( the two options suggested in the first comment work exactly as now (radios are checked but #states aren't fired).  The one in the second comment doesn't even check the radios (does nothing).  Tricky one !

Comment: Please share some more code in relation to the context. Best way would be to put the relevant JS/HTML on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link. It could be the that problem is somewhere other than the code you shared.

Comment: I've put together a [little module](https://github.com/rafamd/states) that creates a field in the user entity (field_measure_system radio buttons) at install time.  It alters the user profile/registration form to add some links (US Metric UK) and a drop down that's conditionally shown with #states.  When going to the registration form, you see that #states works fine when the radios are clicked by hand but not when the US, Metric or UK links are clicked.  The radio buttons selection changes (with states.js) but the #states that depends on that radios seem not to recognize those changes. TNKS!

Comment: on jsfiddle it works !  http://jsfiddle.net/AZdvQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal states are bound to the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, therefore you need to trigger that one too. The following snipped should do what you want:

```
$('#id-of-radio-button').trigger('click').trigger('change');
```